# Приложение посередине: тире или запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Как правильно? Оба?

> Пока мой отец под фонограмму на сцене запевал, я, человек, не переносящий музыку, запивал таблетку от головы.

> Пока мой отец под фонограмму на сцене запевал, я — человек, не переносящий музыку, — запивал таблетку от головы.

Comment: Если с тире верно, то перед тире _музыку_ должна быть запятая, закрывающая причастнвй оборот.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно:

*Пока мой отец под фонограмму на сцене запевал, я — **человек, не переносящий музыку,** — запивал таблетку от головы.*

Оформление по обычным правилам: два тире, запятая закрывает причастный оборот внутри вставки.

Comment: Так всë-таки правильно? А почему тире? Дично я в своëм ответе не был уверен на 100 %, поэтому и удивился.

Comment: В теме приложений можно использовать вставку, если это необходимо.  Основная задача при постановке знаков – это сделать текст ясным для понимания. Поэтому нужное правило можно просто выбрать.

Comment: То есть приложение может быть вставкой?

Comment: А почему бы и нет?  Вставные предложения и словосочетания вносят в основное предложение дополнительные сведения (замечания, уточнения, пояснения, поправки и т. д.).  Будем считать, что это доп. пояснение.  В устной речи это пояснение выделяется паузами.

Comment: Спасибо, плюс вашему ответу.

Comment: Кстати, а почему нельзя запятыми? Интересно таки.

Comment: Запятых много, структура предложения неясная, произношение непонятное.

Comment: Хорошо. В очередной раз доказывает, что в русском языке недостаточно знать правил, рассуждать иногда нужно.

Comment: Но по-моему, запятые тоже не некорректны были бы, Шерон.

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что можно только запятыми:

***Пока мой отец под фонограмму на сцене запевал, я, человек, не переносящий музыку, запивал таблетку от головы.***

Приложение, относящееся к личному местоимению, всегда выделяется запятыми.

О том, когда можно ставить тире, [здесь, в 10-м пункте](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111).

---

Думаю, что тире нельзя поставить, т. к. здесь вроде как не подходят случаи, описанные в 10-м пункте.